# How to change image of a pod in a running kubernetes cluster (pod without deployment)

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I have a running kubernetes cluster for magento2. It has a pod for elasticsearch (you can see code [here](https://github.com/KiweeEu/magento2-on-kubernetes/blob/2.3/deploy/bases/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yaml) ).

I need to change the image from elasticsearch:7.9.0 to a custom image.

Since using kustomize, I tried using a patch:

deploy/es-swap:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: es_swap

bases:
  - ../step-4

patchesJson6902:
- path: patch/es.json
  target:
    group: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co
    version: v1
    kind: Elasticsearch
    name: elasticsearch
```

deploy/es-swap/es.json:

```
[
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/spec/nodeSets/0/podTemplate/spec/containers/0/name",
      "value": "mydockerhubuser/elastic:v7.9.0_custom"
    }
  ]
```

I deployed to patch like this:

```
$ kustomize build deploy/es_swap | kubectl apply -f -
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx unchanged
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
:
elasticsearch.elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/elasticsearch configured
```

but it didn't actually work since it is still using previous image:

```
$ k describe pod elasticsearch-es-elasticsearch-0 | grep image
  Normal   Pulled                  25m   kubelet                  Container image "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.0" already present on machine
```

When checking output of `kustomize build deploy/es_swap` I see that `mydockerhubuser/elastic:v7.9.0_custom` is image of the elasticsearch container. So I don't understand why it is not swapped.

Another option that I was thinking about is that instead of changing the image, I can add initContainers, [as explained here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/1.0/k8s-init-containers-plugin-downloads.html). I am not entirely sure how to do that.

I tried checking rollout and kubernetes patch, but I only see examples that apply them to deployments.

What is the way to change the image of this running pod?

Comment: kubernetes does not allow changing image in non-managed pods. that's just it. if you need to rely on simple pods,you need to delete and recreate the resource with your changes. however, you can create a deployment matching the current labels of your pod, which will make that pod managed by a deployment. then you are able to change the image in the deployment, leading to a pod with the updated image being created

Comment: @meaningqo, please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: The `...-0` name suggests it's being managed by a StatefulSet.  I don't immediately recognize the `/spec/nodeSets/...` JSON path, though.  Do you have the original object you're trying to apply Kustomize to ?

Comment: Fortunately I managed to install the elasticsearch plugins that I needed by adding the initContainers to the elasticsearch yaml, and then apply change. It worked after recreating the pods. So I am good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

kubernetes does not allow changing image in non-managed pods. that's just it.

if you need to rely on simple pods,you need to delete and recreate the resource with your changes.

however, you can create a deployment matching the current labels of your pod, which will make that pod managed by a deployment. then you are able to change the image in the deployment, leading to a pod with the updated image being created

Comment: I managed to install the elasticsearch plugins that I needed by adding the initContainers to the elasticsearch yaml, so for now I ok good. But I might try your method, because I will probably need in the future to upgrade the elasticsearch pod. Thanks for the suggestion